TypeError: dispatcher is null
I'm having some issues, but the main one seems to be the TypeError: dispatcher is null. It appears after several rebuilds of the code. Additionally, in the browser console, I see the warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips on how to debug and fix this problem.
I also see: Warning: Cannot update a component (HotReload) while rendering a different component (wL). To locate the bad setState() call inside wL, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render.

In the VSCode terminal, I see: No ModuleFederationPlugin(s) found.
Follow my code:
page.js
/// <reference types="@module-federation/nextjs-mf/src/include-defaults" />
'use client'

import dynamic from "next/dynamic"

const Footer = dynamic(() => import("container/App"), { ssr: false });

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        Welcome to the Shop app port: 3001
      </h1>
      {Footer ? <Footer /> : <div>Loading...</div>}
    </>
  )
}


next.config.js
const NextFederationPlugin = require("@module-federation/nextjs-mf");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');

const shared = ["react", "react-dom", "next/dynamic"]
const ASSET_PATH = process.env.ASSET_PATH || '/';


module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  pageExtensions: ['mdx', 'md', 'jsx', 'js', 'tsx', 'ts'],

  experimental: {
    isrMemoryCacheSize: 0,
    appDir: true,
  },

  webpack(config, options) {
    const { isServer } = options;

    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: "web-fs",
        remotes: {
          container: `container@https://xx-xx-xx-xx.xx.com.br/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js?v=${Date.now()}`
        },
        filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
        shared: shared,
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'use client': JSON.stringify(true)
      })
    );

    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) =>
      rule.test?.test?.(".svg")
    );

    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        ...fileLoaderRule,
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        resourceQuery: /url/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        resourceQuery: { not: /url/ },
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      }
    );

    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;

    return config;
  },
};


layout.tsx
/// <reference types="@module-federation/nextjs-mf/src/include-defaults" />
'use client'

import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "@next/font/google";
import Providers from "./components/Providers";
import CheckLogin from "./components/CheckLogin";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { Suspense } from "react";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Web Feature Store",
};

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  console.log("layout");
  return (
    <html lang="pt">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers>
          <CheckLogin />
          {children}
        </Providers>

        <br />
        <footer>
          <Footer />
        </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


providers.tsx
"use client";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const Providers = (props: Props) => {
  console.log("providers");
  return <SessionProvider>{props.children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default Providers;

package.json
{
  "name": "web-feature-store-v2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3000",
    "build": "next build && npx tailwind -i app/globals.css -o app/tailwind.css",
    "start": "next start -p 3000",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "5.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "2.6.1",
    "@emotion/react": "11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.10.6",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^7.5.0",
    "@module-federation/nextjs-mf": "6.7.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.2",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.10.2",
    "@next-tools/dynamic": "^0.0.11",
    "@next/font": "13.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/colors": "^3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@radix-ui/primitive": "^1.0.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.5",
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.11.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.33.0",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.9.7",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.40",
    "@types/node": "20.4.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",
    "external-remotes-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "lib-utils-ts": "^2.0.4-stable",
    "lucide-react": "^0.274.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "13.1.6",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "next-external-remotes-plugin": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.6",
    "reactstrap": "^9.2.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.4",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.0.2",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.16.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "browser": {
    "child_process": false,
    "fs": false,
    "tls": false
  }
}

the right answer....

Does it say where the invalid hook is? Like what file or line.

Here does this question maybe help? This Link

It doesn't say where the invalid hook is, it just appears in a generic way, unfortunately the link doesn't help, because the error mentioned there is in the connection link
